# How to stop a layer updating in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, gradient

```
class DR(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, orginal, latent_dims):
        super(DR, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dims=latent_dims
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(orginal, 1000)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(1000, 2000)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(2000, latent_dims)
        


    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear3(x))
        return x
```

In this DR class, i don't want to update linear1, and linear2 in the traning time. That means, the layer should be same as it initialized, I only want to update linear3 in the traning time. How can i do this ?

I expect a solution of this proeblem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to set `requires_grad` attributes to False for all the parameters in those layers.

```
model = DR(64, 100)
for layer in [model.linear1, model.linear2]:
    for p in layer.parameters():
        p.requires_grad_(False)
print([(n, p.requires_grad) for n,p in model.named_parameters()])
```

Answer (score 1):

What appears like an underused feature of PyTorch is that the [`requires_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html), which is meant to disable inference caching for gradient computation can be called on `torch.Tensor` (as an [in place](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.requires_grad_.html?highlight=requires_grad#torch.Tensor.requires_grad_) and [out of place](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.requires_grad.html?highlight=requires_grad#torch.Tensor.requires_grad) operation) but also on `nn.Module` ([in place](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=requires_grad#torch.nn.Module.requires_grad_)).

In your case, you can simply write in two lines:

```
model.linear1.requires_grad_(False)
model.linear2.requires_grad_(False)
```

Comment: Nice! Never used this feature before. I think you meant `requires_grad_`, the one with underscore.